# Pandas replace using regex=true replaces partial word

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, replace

I want to replace the whole word translation from the input'. The code written replace a part of string instead of whole word.

```
import string
import pandas as pd
 text=pd.read_csv("TranslationInput.csv",sep = ';', keep_default_na=False)
 change=pd.read_csv("germanTranslation.csv",  sep='\s*:\s*')
 toupdate = dict(zip(change.german, change.english))
 ttext = text['inputcolumn'].replace(toupdate, regex=True)
 print(ttext)
```

German translation:

| german | english |
| --- | --- |
| Schlauch | hose |
| Schlauchanschluss | hose connection |
| Anschluss | adapter plate |
| Anschlussleitung | connecting cable |
| Warnschild | warning sign |
| Warnung vor Handverletzungen | hand injury warning |

Input:

| inputcolumn | english |
| --- | --- |
| Warnschild: Warnung vor Handverletzungen |  |
| Schlauchanschluss |  |
| Anschlussleitung |  |

output:

```
warning sign: hand injury warning
hoseanschluss
adapter plateleitung
```

Answer (score 2):

Try putting word boundaries for your dictionary keys:

```
text['inputcolumn'].replace(dict(zip(change['german'].map(r'\b{}\b'.format),change['english'])),regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    warning sign: hand injury warning
1                      hose connection
2                     connecting cable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    toupdate = dict(zip(change.german, change.english))
```

This produces *a* mapping from German to English.
But it suffers from the prefix effect, e.g.
an "Anschluss" translation may mask
a longer "Anschlussleitung" match.

A python `dict` is sensitive to the order in which you insert items.
I recommend that you carefully order the `change.german` `g` entries.
Rather than ascending alphabetic, you should order them by descending
`(len(g), g)`. There is a convenient
[reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
flag for that.
The effect would be to prefer translating a longer match instead of a shorter prefix.

---

Consider tokenizing input words with
[spacy](https://pypi.org/project/spacy).
It offers good multi-lingual support,
and it understands the morphology of compound words
far better than regex-based approaches ever will.